# When I unInstall app, running IDE and install app, Error type 3,WelcomeActivity does not exist

Tags: android, android-activity, reinstall

When I uninstall app, running IDE and try to install app,

Error Message:

> Starting: Intent{ act=android.intent.action.MAIN
>   cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.XX.XX.WelcomeActivity.
>   Error type 3,WelcomeActivity does not exist

But if I disconnect phone and computer, running IDE and try to install app, install success.

I have no idea. Why?

Comment: uncheck application deploing in Rub/Debug configuration.

Comment: I used  Deploy default apk.  I have two phones. One phone Android System 4.1.1 don't have this problem. The other one System 5.0 have the problem...

Comment: hm. try to file - invalidate caches and restart

Comment: hi, Recently, I found if I use "adb uninstall com.xx.xxx", i will install success.I guess ,use system uninstall, some config not delete. Lg2, Android 5.0.2